# CSS Grid layouts for a responsive website

Tags: html, css

Though I'm new to CSS Grid and I am currently working on a project to perfect the act of using it perfectly.

I am trying to build a cake website similar to this https://waracake.com [A cake website] and the goal is to get all my cakes arrange in same way as this cakes, have tried every methods with the tutorials on YouTube but all my efforts was abortive.

Here is my code

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  /*grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);*/
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .8em 1.2em;
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
```

```html
<main id="grid">
  <div class="product-container" class="grid">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 1.jpeg" alt="cake1">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Wedding Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 10,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 2.jpeg" alt="cake2">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Birthday Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 7,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 3.jpeg" alt="cake3">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Valentines Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 10,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 4.jpeg" alt="cake4">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Birthday Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 9,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 6.jpeg" alt="cake6">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Wedding Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 12,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="product-grid">
            <img src="images/cake 7.jpeg" alt="cake7">
            <div class="product-content">
              <h3>Wedding Cake</h3>
              <p>Price <br> ₦ 5,000</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Please, help me I want to get results similar to this designs

Comment: use `display:flex` in `ul` also define width and spacing of `li` elements

Comment: I tried to add a comment but do not have enough points for that. So here goes my question for more clarification or my understanding, From what I am trying to understand you are trying to add a table but you want 'n' columns instead of 1? You're setting a single <-ul-> and all <-li-> lies within, I would suggest you use Bootstrap templates for getting grids and use a for loop to run across your items so that it can add more items as needed dynamically. also you can use this same code for removing bullets to make it look more like thumbnails.
add css, ul { list-style: none; display: flex; } img

Comment: I tried using flex in the ul and it worked fine, but while i tried using width it failed to give me the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
 display: inline-flex;
 list-style: none;
}
li {
 margin: 20px;
}
```